# How do I constrain the outputs of Gaussian Processes in PYMC?

Tags: pymc

So I have a very challenging MCMC run I would like to do in PyMC, which I have run several times before for much simpler analyses. However, my newest challenge requires me to combine many different Gaussian Processes in a very specific way, and I don't know enough about Gaussian processes in general or how they are implemented in PyMC to engineer the code I need.

Here is the problem I am trying to tackle:

The data I have is five time series (we'll call them A(t), B(t), C(t), D(t), and E(t)) , each measurement of which has Gaussian/Normal uncertainties. Each of these can be modeled as the product of one series-specific efficiency function and one underlying function shared between all five time series, so A(t) = a(t) * f(t), B(t) = b(t) * f(t), C(t) = c(t) * f(t), etc... I need to measure the posterior for f(t), or more specifically, the posterior of the integral of f(t) dt over a domain.

So I have read over some documentation about implementing Gaussian Processes in PyMC, but I have a few additional wrinkles with my efficiency functions that need to be addressed specifically before I can start coding up my model. Mainly -

1) I have no strong prior about the shape of the efficiency functions a(t), b(t), etc... So long as they vary smoothly there is no shape that is strongly forbidden.

2) These efficiency functions are physically bound to be between 0 and 1 for all times.  So while I have no prior on the shape of the curve it has to fall between these bounds. I do have some prior about its typical value but since I need to marginalize over it I can't put too many other constraints on this.

Has anyone out there tackled a similar type of problem before, and what might be the most elegant way to guarantee that my efficiency priors are implemented in this complex MCMC run? I simply don't know enough about Gaussian Processes/Covariance functions to know how to force these constraints on the data.

Comment: Something like this has come up for me and others in the past, here are some notes on how we handled it: http://healthyalgorithms.com/2012/08/29/mcmc-in-python-approximate-derivative-constrained-gaussian-processes-with-pymc-gp/

Comment: I did not know about pymc Potentials! I think that is exactly what I need for this work...

Comment: Great! You should post a small example showing how you do it, in case some future web-searcher lands on this question.